# Image Get Jagged in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, adobe-illustrator

When images imported into unity gets jagged.

[Jagged Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7opxo.png)

But the unity 2d pack sprites does not gets jagged:

[Jagged Image VS 2D Pack Sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9CW8.png)

I do all tasks like:

1 - Disabling and Enabling Mip Maps

2 - Fit texture size for usage

3 - Change filter mode

4 - Set Compression to None

5 - Importing Images from Photoshop instead of illustrator

Details:
Unity Version 5.5.0f
Images Created in Adobe Illustrator CC 2017

Comment: What format are the images you're importing?

Comment: All of them is png (256 x 256)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved it.

You should import your textures and sprites in the size that you want for example:

If you need a 64 x 64 texture you should create and import your texture in 128 x 128 size.

By doing this the texture will become anti aliased and a little fade.

Thanks.

Comment: How to import the texture in 128 x 128 size in Unity, can you please help to illustrate that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Go into **Import Settings** by clicking on the file in the project window
- Increase pixels per unit to 200-300
- **For all build platforms:**

  - Increase Max Size to 8192 (or highest)
  - If you get the option, increase the compressor quality to 100
- *Not recommended*: In the scene, reduce scale and increase width/height

If none of that works:

- Use a higher resolution image, or **increase import resolution of vector image**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you should try a higher resolution. 
Another option is to download plugin SVGImporter (You can export to svg from AI) and import .svg files. Then you should get 100% smooth images

Comment: I Have SVGImporter and tested it by that, but my image has drop shadow that not supported by SVGImporter

Comment: Thank you. for your suggested way.

Comment: I told you to use a higher resolution, twice.

Comment: Thanks. i forget that. you are hero.